# Install ASP.NET Core Runtime using PowerShell without internet access

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I would like to be able to install ASP.NET Core runtime during a release in Azure DevOps (if its missing om the target machine), however My remote machines does not have internet access.

This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script appears to be the "official" way of doing this, but it from the look of it this requires an internet access till be able to download the .exe from the Azure Feed(?).

Has anyone been able to modify this so it downloads the file from a place located on the local network path/url?

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to install .Net Core SDK when I have the `.exe` in my local drive, I assuming it's the same thing for the .Net Core runtime file.

Just not use the PowerShell installation script and install the `.exe` in the Command Line. in `.yaml` pipeline:

```
- script: |
   "D:\dotnet-runtime.exe" /s
   TIMEOUT /T 500 /nobreak
```

Explanation:

`"D:\dotnet-runtime.exe"` start to install the .exe file (replace it with your .exe path).

`/s` - Silent mode (no popup and "next" buttons).

`TIMEOUT /T 500 /nobreak` - To make the CMD waiting until the installation will be finished (without it the pipeline move on and the installation cancelled).